# Dictionary of functions for all function in class

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm relatively new to python and I have a class that has a bunch of different function. I read in the user input and depending on the user input I call a different function. Instead of having a bunch of if else statements I thought it would be better to have a dictionary of functions so currently my class looks like this:

```
class Foo:

  def func1(self):
    #do something

  def func2(self, arg1):
    #do something else

  def func3(self, arg1, arg2):
   #do something

  def func4(self, arg1):
    #do something

  def __init__(self):
    self.functions = {"FUNC2": func2, "FUNC4":func4}

  def run_loop(self):
    while 1:
      user_input = raw_input()

      cmd = user_input.split(' ')[0]

      if cmd in self.functions:
        self.functions[cmd].__get__(self, type(self))()
      else:
        #call other functions
```

I'm calling this in a `main.py` like so:

```
c = Class()

c.run_loop()
```

My issue is that I'm getting the following error `NameError`: global name 'func2' is not defined`. I'm not really sure why this is happening. I get the error in the constructor. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use `self.func` in `__init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the function is within the class by adding `self` before it.

```
  def __init__(self):
      self.functions = {"FUNC2": self.func2, "FUNC4":self.func4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use self to access class functions from other function in same class. The corrected code will be

```
self.functions = {"FUNC2": self.func2, "FUNC4":self.func4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is not identified within the class. Function "func2" & "func4" are part of the class and can be referred using the self...